# WordPress Taxonomies - relating parent/child terms across different taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm developing a wine website in WordPress. I have a custom post type of Wine and I'm trying to come up with the best way to organize the taxonomies. I need to be able to organize my wines by Country, Region, and Producer so it seems logical to have those three taxonomies. The difficulty comes in the fact that Producers are childern of Regions, and Regions are children of Countries.  On the front end, I need to be able to show all the Regions in a Country and all the Producers in a Region, and then the wines by that Producer.  How can I achieve this if I can't set parent/child relationships of terms across different taxonomies? Is there a better way to organize this that I'm overlooking?

I tried setting up just one taxonomy and then writing code to identify Country, Region, Producer based on whether it was a child or grandchild term. Sort of worked but not a very clean solution.